# Difference between vm_offset_t, (void *), and mach_vm_size_t

Tags: c, macos, mach

I'm trying to understand [this code for reading virtual memory mappings](http://www.newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=12-1-vmmap.c) but I'm having trouble understanding the different data types as I can't find any good documentation.

What is the difference between `vm_offset_t`, `void *`, and `mach_vm_size_t`? On my machine they all seem to be 8 bytes (64-bit) and used to navigate virtual memory. What are the differences between their purposes? What is the point of having these different types?

EDIT:

For instance, in the linked code:

```c
unsigned char *
readProcessMemory (int pid, mach_vm_address_t addr, mach_msg_type_number_t *size)
{
    // Helper function to read process memory (a la Win32 API of same name)
    // To make it easier for inclusion elsewhere, it takes a pid, and
    // does the task_for_pid by itself. Given that iOS invalidates task ports
    // after use, it's actually a good idea, since we'd need to reget anyway

    task_t  t;
    task_for_pid(mach_task_self(),pid, &t);
        mach_msg_type_number_t  dataCnt = size;
        vm_offset_t readMem;
    
    // Use vm_read, rather than mach_vm_read, since the latter is different
    // in iOS.

        kern_return_t kr = vm_read(t,        // vm_map_t target_task,
                     addr,     // mach_vm_address_t address,
                     *size,     // mach_vm_size_t size
                     &readMem,     //vm_offset_t *data,
                     size);     // mach_msg_type_number_t *dataCnt

        if (kr) {
                // DANG..
                fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read target task's memory @%p - kr 0x%x\n" , addr, kr);
                 return NULL;
                }

    return ( (unsigned char *) readMem);

}
```

According to [this documentation of the vm_read function](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/vm_read.html), the `data_out` parameter is an "Out-pointer to dynamic array of bytes returned by the read."

But in the code above they pass in `&readMem` (which is type `vm_offset_t *`) for `data_out`. I'm confused how `readMem is being used here - is it a pointer to the dynamic array of bytes returned by the read? Or does it actually contain the dynamic array of bytes? Is vm_offset_t a pointer or an address? What is its purpose?

Similarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vm_offset_t`, `void*`, and `mach_vm_size_t` are all internally synonymous with `unsigned long`, but they are used to make the code more readable and expressive.

`vm_read` returns an *address* in `readMem`, meaning that `readMem` will need to be cast to a pointer and dereferenced to access its value.

Also, the memory region pointed to by `readMem` is allocated by the kernel, so it needs to be deallocated with [vm_deallocate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1585284-vm_deallocate). To avoid this, consider using [vm_read_overwrite](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1585371-vm_read_overwrite) which will populate the buffer it is supplied.